# Should [encrypted-home] be a synonym of [ecryptfs]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Should the tag [encrypted-home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/encrypted-home) be a synonym of [ecryptfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ecryptfs)? While there are other ways to encrypt a home directory, Ecryptfs is the official method under Ubuntu. All three questions tagged [encrypted-home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/encrypted-home) are about Ecryptfs.

I think the tag should be made a synonym, rather than deleted, because its name is more discoverable to non-technical users.

Answer (score 6):

I would say yes.

However, before we do **anything** [we need to read the crypto.se post on the stewardship of the ecryptfs tags.](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132/stewardship-of-an-ecryptfs-tag)

tl;dr:

- For technical process (eg "How to I encrypt this in Ubuntu?"), Ask
  Ubuntu wants those.
- As above for non-Ubuntu, to Unix & Linux
- For underlying theory Crypto and Security are probably better audiences.

<sub>(borrowed from Oli's answer there).</sub>

I will ping Dustin Kirkland and find out if he wants this, because I think that for something that he put so much effort into trying to manage properly on Stack Exchange, we should consult him before doing anything.

Comment: +1, I'm good with this.  encrypted-home on Ubuntu, for almost all purposes, means "eCryptfs".  Thanks for asking!  We're loving Stack Exchange for eCryptfs frequently asked questions!